# how to customise the bootstrap grid.less file; 16 columns for desktop and 12 columns for tablet

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I want to generate 16 columns for desktop and 12 columns for tablet and mobile. bootstrap uses the float-grid-columns, make-grid-column functions to generate the grid. I tried modifying it, however couldnt get the result.

```
.float-grid-columns(@class) {
  .col(@index) { // initial
    @item: ~".col-@{class}-@{index}";
    .col((@index + 1), @item);
  }
  .col(@index, @list) when (@index =< @grid-columns) { // general
    @item: ~".col-@{class}-@{index}";
    .col((@index + 1), ~"@{list}, @{item}");
  }
  .col(@index, @list) when (@index > @grid-columns) { // terminal
    @{list} {
      float: left;
    }
  }
  .col(1); // kickstart it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstraps built-in classes.

16-column desktop example (keep in mind, this is the HTML solution to a CSS-related question, however should give the same result based on your question):

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p>This is a column</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p>This is a column</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p>This is a column</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p>This is a column</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p>This is a column</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p>This is a column</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p>This is a column</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p>This is a column</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p>This is a column</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p>This is a column</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p>This is a column</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p>This is a column</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p>This is a column</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p>This is a column</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p>This is a column</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p>This is a column</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div
    </div>
```

You'd want to make sure you set padding/margin to whatever necessary, as Bootstrap has built in padding/margins, which will probably give it a different structure than you are looking for.

You can then customize it a bit to turn to 12 columns for tablet and mobile, using col-xs-4 and col-sm-4, and possibly removing certain columns under a certain screen resolution with CSS.

Refer to http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: I dont like to do it manually. I want to customise this file to generate my grid: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins/grid-framework.less

Comment: Ignore the rest, was typing this as you made your comment. Reviewing the link now. ------ I can't respond to comments as I don't have 50 reputation, but if you follow the example I used above and place a col-sm-4 before the col-lg-3's as well as use some media queries in css to display: none 1 of the columns per set of 4 columns once the screen is resized, you should get your desired result. I would make it for you, but then you don't learn =) If you need any help feel free to ask. My solution isn't the only, but it is a solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify those generating mixins themselves, what you need is to modify how they are used (see `grid.less`), something like this (to be included *after* Bootstrap code, or more specifically after `grid.less` or (with corresponding additions) instead of it to reduce unused code):

```
// import this only if you don't import "bootstrap.less" itself:
@import "<bootstrap/less>/variables.less";

& {

@import (multiple) "<bootstrap/less>/mixins/grid-framework.less";

@grid-columns: 16;

@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
  .make-grid(sm);
}

@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
  .make-grid(md);
}

@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
  .make-grid(lg);
}

}
```

Where `<bootstrap/less>` is the path to the corresponding Bootstrap dir.

Answer (score 0):

```
    I achieved it by:

    on variables.less, added:
    ----------------------------
    @grid-xs-columns: 4;
    @grid-sm-columns: 12;
    @grid-md-columns: 16;

    on grid.less file, modified:
    -------------------------------
    .make-grid(xs,@grid-xs-columns);
    // Small grid
    //
    // Columns, offsets, pushes, and pulls for the small device range, from phones
    // to tablets.
    @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
        .make-grid(sm,@grid-sm-columns);
    }

    // Medium grid
    //
    // Columns, offsets, pushes, and pulls for the desktop device range.
    @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
       .make-grid(md,@grid-md-columns);
    }

on grid-framework.less; modified
--------------------------------
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = width) and (@index > 0) {
    .col-@{class}-@{index} when (@class = xs){
      width: percentage((@index / @grid-xs-columns));  
    }  
    .col-@{class}-@{index} when (@class = sm){
      width: percentage((@index / @grid-sm-columns));  
    }  
    .col-@{class}-@{index} when (@class = md){
      width: percentage((@index / @grid-md-columns));  
    }  
}
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = push) and (@index > 0) {
  .col-@{class}-push-@{index} when (@class = xs){
    left: percentage((@index / @grid-xs-columns));
  }
  .col-@{class}-push-@{index} when (@class = sm){
    left: percentage((@index / @grid-sm-columns));
  }
  .col-@{class}-push-@{index} when (@class = md){
    left: percentage((@index / @grid-md-columns));
  }
}
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = push) and (@index = 0) {
  .col-@{class}-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
}
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = pull) and (@index > 0) {
  .col-@{class}-pull-@{index} when (@class = xs){
    right: percentage((@index / @grid-xs-columns));
  }
  .col-@{class}-pull-@{index} when (@class = sm){
    right: percentage((@index / @grid-sm-columns));
  }
  .col-@{class}-pull-@{index} when (@class = md){
    right: percentage((@index / @grid-md-columns));
  }
}
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = pull) and (@index = 0) {
  .col-@{class}-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
}
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = offset) {
  .col-@{class}-offset-@{index}  when (@class = xs){
    margin-left: percentage((@index / @grid-xs-columns));
  }
    .col-@{class}-offset-@{index}  when (@class = sm){
    margin-left: percentage((@index / @grid-sm-columns));
  }
    .col-@{class}-offset-@{index}  when (@class = md){
    margin-left: percentage((@index / @grid-md-columns));
  }

}

// Basic looping in LESS
.loop-grid-columns(@index, @class, @type) when (@index >= 0) {
  .calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type);
  // next iteration
  .loop-grid-columns((@index - 1), @class, @type);
}

// Create grid for specific class
.make-grid(@class,@numbers) {
  .float-grid-columns(@class);
  .loop-grid-columns(@numbers, @class, width);
  .loop-grid-columns(@numbers, @class, pull);
  .loop-grid-columns(@numbers, @class, push);
  .loop-grid-columns(@numbers, @class, offset);
}
```